# Add parameter to pager link url

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, pager

Pager link points to something like `www.example.com/node/100?page=1`. I need pass addtional parameters through this link: `www.example.com/node/100?page=1&my_param_1=1&my_param_2=2`.
For example I have a view with a pager. I want every link in this pager to point an anchor (for example Quicktabs tab). How it can be done?

Comment: That IS how it is done. I don't think your question is so much how to pass additional parameters as it is how to *parse* those additional parameters.

Comment: How to PASS. For example I have a view with a pager. I want every link in this pager to point an anchor (for example Quicktabs tab).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include 'parameters' in your pager theme array:

...
    ['tablePager'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => theme('pager', array(
            'element' => 0,
            'parameters' => array( 'name' => 'value' )
        ))
    ),

Taken from: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7

Comment: Your answer helped me with a similar problem. I used this code to add a parameter to my links.

$pager = theme('pager', array('quantity', array('quantity' => $total), 'parameters' => array( 'op' => 'Submit' )));